# How to search for a number exactly in JPA repo instead of using LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have a JPA repo containing the search method query and the query works as it but instead of using Like I need it to search for the exact number or similar number, for example currently the if the amountContributed was 1120 if I typed in 1 and searched it the project would come up, if I typed 11 it would as well and 112.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.url LIKE %?1%"
        + " OR p.description LIKE %?1% OR p.amountContributed LIKE %?1%")
public List<Project> search(String keyword);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: 1 would also find 112, can you please make a table with data and which data should be in the end result and which not, so basically produce a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for the exact number use =

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.url LIKE %?1%"
        + " OR p.description LIKE %?1% OR p.amountContributed = ?1")
public List<Project> search(String keyword);
```